# Angular plugins/method for smooth scroll

Tags: angular

I'm not talking about anchor scrolling, I've found some plugins but they were all deprecated/didn't work. Does anyone know any scroll plugins that work for latest Angular, something like this: https://locomotivemtl.github.io/locomotive-scroll/

Answer (score 0):

You can use a solution from [MDN Docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/scroll-behavior) `scroll-behavior: smooth;` to create smooth scroll, [example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-scroll-smooth-bevpx6-ub9zjf) in Angular.

Comment: Isn't this anchor scrolling, I'm talking about the scrollbar/scroll behavior on the whole page that has a "bouncy" feeling